# (Part2) SharePoint 2010, Powershell - Loop through all Document Libraries, create view and set it as default.

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

This is a query leading on from another that was very kindly worked on by @marek-grzenkowicz.

**Issue 1)** The script is generating an error when it runs. It was mentioned that you can't modify an element of the collection that is being enumerated. Can you show me how to work around this? Despite changes being made to avoid the problem it's still happening

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a  collection: Collection was modified; enumera tion operation may not execute.. At C:\Users\quickdev1\Documents\LoopThroughAl lLibrariesCreateView.ps1:7 char:10
+   foreach <<<< ($list in $web.Lists) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperati     on: (Microsoft.Share...on+SPEnumerator:S     PEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

**Issue 2)** I would like to put in some logic to check if an existing view is already there with the name "Detailed" and if so to skip that Library but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

If anyone could help it would be awesome.

Thanks,

Ashley

**Full Script**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$siteURL = "http://sp14fdev01/"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
  foreach($list in $web.Lists) {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
// the variables `$web` and `$list` already reference the objects you need
      //$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteURL) ;
      //$web = $site.OpenWeb($SiteURL);

// new instance of the list is necessary to avoid the error "Collection was modified"
      $newList = $web.Lists.item($list.ID);

      $viewfields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection 
      $viewfields.Add("DocIcon") 
      $viewfields.Add("LinkFilename") 
      $viewfields.Add("_UIVersionString") 
      $viewfields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") 
      $viewfields.Add("Created") 
      $viewfields.Add("Modified") 
      $viewfields.Add("Editor") 
      [void]$newList.Views.Add("Detailed", $viewfields, "", 100, $true, $true)

      $newList.Update();

// setting the default view
      $view=$newList.Views["Detailed"]
      $view.DefaultView = $true
      $view.Update()
    }
  }

  $web.Dispose();
}

$site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a for-loop instad of a foreach since you are modifying the collection you are looping over.

Like this:

```
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $listCounter = $web.Lists.Count

    for($i=0;$i -le $listCounter;$i++)
    {
        $list = $web.Lists[$i]
        //etc....

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Ole, Thanks. Where should I continue the script from? 

from here -  
if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
// the variables `$web` and `$list` already reference the objects you need
....?